# How do update a database through Javascript, then reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, database

So, I'm making a website similar to FML and others, where people can post things and others can like/dislike and comment.

Right now, I have it so when somoene clicks "like", it's a link that calls "/like/(post id)", which calls a function that increments the database, then reloads the page.

I'd like to find a way to do this without having to do that.  A friend said to try ajax or javascript, but i'm completely uneducated in them.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: I would recommend to use ajax to a PHP file, but you will need to see some tutorials about this...

Comment: You should also note that when using PHP you can pass variables through the url, so instead of having myPHPfile.php/like/(post id), you should be using myPHPfile.php?action=like&postid=(post id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to explain an AJAX request in its entirety, but this should point you in the right direction.
Instead of reloading the page, have /like/ return the number of likes.
Then have the number in a selectable element, like

```
<a id="postid" href="#" onclick="like(this);return false;" class="likebtn">Like</a>
<span id="postid-likes">0</span>
```

Then make the javascript function

```
<script>
function like(element) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(element.id+"-likes").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/like/"+element.id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: -1 for recommending inline javascript and you didn't send any data or identifier as to _what_ item got liked.

Comment: Raynos perhaps your time would be better spent writing the correct answer ?

Comment: This function could go in one of your javascript files, this was meant as an example of how to make a request, not where to put your javascript code. And "postid" was meant to be some unique identifier for each item created by PHP. Oh yeah, the url should be something like /like/postid then.

Comment: This works. Except it took me a little bit to get it working. I finally noticed that you create the object as "xmlHTTP" but everywhere else you use it as "xmlhttp"